# Error with \tableofcontents when using "\(...\)" in section

Tags: table-of-contents

I want to type math equation in section headers, but I had some error with \tableofcontents command.

When I compile this file

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter 1}
\section{This is an equation: \(x=1\)}

\tableofcontents

\end{document}
```

It gives out these error

```
Bad math environment delimiter. ...ak or <return> to continue without it.}}{1}
Extra }, or forgotten $. ...ak or <return> to continue without it.}}{1}
Missing $ inserted. ...ak or <return> to continue without it.}}{1}
Missing } inserted. \tableofcontents
```

But this file compile just fine

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter 1}
\section{This is an equation: $x=1$}

\tableofcontents

\end{document}
```

So what is the cause of this error? Is there any way to use `\(...\)` in the section header, or I have to use `$...$`?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Add `\usepackage{fixltx2e}` to your document preamble (or use `$...$`).